# Vuex action not waiting to finish axios promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I encounter a strange situation developing an application in Laravel + VueJS/Vuex stack.

I understand that if a promise is not returned the parent function calling it will not wait for it to resolve so things will go asynchronous. Axios returns a promise by default when calling a resourse through http.

So i have the parent function which looks like this:

```
fetchInvoiceSeries() {
  var arr = []
  let invsrs = this.$store.getters['getInvoiceSeries']
  if (invsrs == null) {
    return this.$store
      .dispatch('get_invoice_series')
      .then(() => {
        invsrs = this.$store.getters['getInvoiceSeries']
        if (invsrs != null) {
          invsrs.forEach(function(s) {
            arr.push({
              value: s.id,
              text: s.series + ' / ' + s.increment
            })
          })
          this.series = arr
        } else {
          console.log('Error while fetching invoice series!')
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
  } else {
    invsrs.forEach(function(s) {
      arr.push({
        value: s.id,
        text: s.series + ' / ' + s.increment
      })
    })
    this.series = arr
  }
}
```

And here is the function defined in action part of the vuex module:

```
get_invoice_series({ commit }) {
    return get('/api/series/0')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data && typeof response.data !== undefined) {
                let payload = response.data
                commit('SET_INVOICE_SERIES', payload)
            } else {
                console.log('error', error)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error', error)
        })
},
```

So as you can see i am returning the get request from axios inside the action. In the parent i am calling the action and the "then" keyword in order to do some processing after the action it's done. Also i am using arrow function because i need the context in the parent function in order to call this.$store ...

**The problem** is that even after checking the getter to see if the state have the invoice series and getting them using the get_invoice_series action i still don't have the invoice series in memory judging by the code i wrote. The console keeps loggin '**Error while fetching invoice series!**' ***the first time i execute the code and the second time (after the information exists in state), the code skips fetching the invoice series (as expected)***.

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong ? Thank you!

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as obviously wrong. I suggest using more console logging to check the order of when the various sections run relative to each other. How is `get` declared? What does the `SET_INVOICE_SERIES` mutation look like? Does the `getInvoiceSeries` getter do anything aside from returning the state property?

Comment: It's just a set in the state the `SET_INVOICE_SERIES` mutation. The get is declared to verify if the length of the array is bigger then 1 and returns the array if true.

Comment: 1. Please post the code for the getter `getInvoiceSeries`. 2. What is the initial value for the corresponding property in the `state`? 3. How are you importing/declaring the function `get`?

Answer (score 2):

Your error comes from `invsrs` being null the first time, and not null the second time.

This means that your function `get_invoice_series({ commit })` is asynchronous, and that it returns a promise.

For more readability, maybe you should make your call independently from your `return` statement, using `async/await` expressions :

```js
async get_invoice_series({ commit }) {
    const response = await get('/api/series/0')
    if (response.data === undefined) return null    
    const payload = response.data
    commit('SET_INVOICE_SERIES', payload)
    return payload
},
```

And then make your calls wait for this fetch to process :

```js
async fetchInvoiceSeries() {
  let arr = []
  const invsrs = await this.$store.getters['getInvoiceSeries']
  // ...
```

It's pure conjecture here, let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Rn i'm checking your suggestions out and i will come back to flag the answer as correct if that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: It's not working still.. Anyway the getter is synchronous so it may not need the await operator as you mentioned, i guess you referred to the action dispatch to use the await operator. Anyway thanks for help but i cannot mark your question as correct since it didn't solve my problem.